Telegram bot - 'invalid content was found' when trying to add TelegramBots
I'm getting started with creating a Telegram bot (following this tutorial) and I'm having trouble adding the TelegramBots library.
According to the tutorial, I should have added the framework this way:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
        <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

But I got the Dependency 'org.telegram:telegrambots:6.0.1' not found error, so I assumed it was because the version of the TelegramBots was outdated, so I changed it to the newest version:
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
    <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.1</version>
  </dependency>

For which I instead got the error,
Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":dependency}'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":parent, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":packaging,[...] "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":reporting, "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":profiles}' is expected.
I was told I should update the code to,
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-longpolling</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
            <artifactId>telegrambots-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

But I get exactly the same error. I'm unsure what exactly is wrong or missing with Maven, so any pointers would be really useful.
